# How to export data from database to excel sheet using spring MVC?

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-mvc, export-to-excel

How to export data from MySQL table to excel using spring MVC?

I tried many from Google, but nothings works. As I required, I tried [this](http://javapapers.com/spring/excel-export-in-spring-mvc) code but its not from a database.

How to export from a database?

Comment: What library do you use to read/write an Excel file, [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/download.html)? You just need to set cell values according to the data you may fetch from a database.

Comment: I fixed all of your formatting problems and errors, and finally practically nothing left from your original question. I think, the problem in this case is a layer 8 problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Apache POI, I recommend you to use another library to write Excel file, [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com). You can export your data directly from MySQL to Excel using the ResultSet. See here [how to export ResultSet to Excel](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/export-resultset-to-excel.html).

```
    ExcelDocument xls = new ExcelDocument();
    xls.easy_WriteXLSFile_FromResultSet("Excel.xls", resultset,  
              new ExcelAutoFormat(Styles.AUTOFORMAT_EASYXLS1), "Sheet name");
```

or

```
    ExcelDocument xls = new ExcelDocument();
    xls.easy_WriteXLSXFile_FromResultSet("Excel.xlsx", resultset,  
              new ExcelAutoFormat(Styles.AUTOFORMAT_EASYXLS1), "Sheet name");
```